# "Bridge" Raspberry Pi wlan0 to eth0

Tags: networking

I would like to have the following setup. Please note that I'm a beginner therefore "Bridge" is in quotes.

```
                  WiFi                       LAN
192.168.1.0/24 <~.~.~.~> (wlan0) RPi (eth0) ----- device (192.168.1.15)

Firewall 192.168.1.10
DNS&DHCP 192.168.1.1
```

I'm using RPi 3B with Debian Stretch. The *device* is some device that is not able to connect to WiFi and has the static ip.
Connecting my notebook to the network should allow me to access the web interface of the *device*. 
I've already searched the web for days - with zero success.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: They are on the same network, therefore they should be able to communicate without you doing anything. You don't need to bridge wlan and cabled lan to communicate within the same network. How is your firewall configured and why has it an extra address? What is the address if your PI? Is it within the 192.168.1.X network?

Comment: the firewall is on 192.168.1.10 and the 192.168.1.1 is a WinServer2012R2 doing DNS and DHCP services

Comment: See my edit, which address does the lan interface on the PI have?

Comment: wlan0 192.168.1.125 (from dhcp)
lan0 I've tried different setting none worked. Which IP should I configure?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. [Using the Raspberry Pi as an access point to share an internet connection (bridge)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) may help with configuring a bridge. Normally with a bridged interface the IP Address is assigned to the bridge, not the interfaces which are bridged together. It would be simpler to plug the "device" into your router

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Of course it would be easier to plug the device into the router the problem is that I would need a few 100 meters of wiring through the whole plant. The whole plant is covered with WiFi and so I thought I could connect the PI to the WiFi (which I did successfully) and then share his network connection through it's LAN interface. Even after several Internet researches I've no idea how to configure the RPi to share the connection. On Windows I'm able to do it.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip a` to your post by editing it, as well as the contents of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you have a router running on subnet 192.168.1.0/24. This router also works as access point for that subnet. The RasPi is connected as client to the access point.

In this case it is not possible to bridge **wlan0** and **eth0** on the RasPi. To bridge a WiFi client connection it must be supported by the WiFi device with **WDS** (Wirless Distribution Service) and `4addr`. The WiFi on-board chip of the RasPi doesn't support it. For details you can look at [Raspberry Pi WiFi to Ethernet Bridge for a server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81518/79866).

I see three possibilities:

1. Purchase an USB/WiFi dongle that supports **WDS**. Then you can make a real bridge.
2. If you only want to connect to the web server on the device, you can use routing with port forwarding. An example of this setup for a printer you can find at [Share Ethernet printer on Wi-Fi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88848/79866).
3. You can use a pseudo bridge with proxy arp. For an example of this setup you can look at [Workaround for a wifi bridge on a Raspberry Pi with proxy arp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88955/79866).

Comment: I chose your first option an bought a real bridging device.