# I want a raspberry pi network bridge to my non-wireless PC with the same IP address if my PC had wireless internet (192.168.1.xx and not 192.168.56.x)

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireless, access-point, bridge

I want a raspberry pi network bridge to my non-wireless PC with the same IP address if my PC had wireless internet (192.168.**1**.xx and not 192.168.**56**.x)
I connect the pc to the internet via raspberry though my IP is something like 192.168.**56**.1
But I need it to be 192.168.**1**.xx
I tried some methods but those didn't work.
I NEED the same address though,
Thank you very much if you help.

Comment: `I tried some methods` - which ones, so I don't repeat them ... however, I believe it's not possible to share wifi connection with ethernet without NAT

Comment: see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96617/bridge-raspberry-pi-wlan0-to-eth0 - it's not possible with onboard wifi

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use NetworkManager to perform the setup.

Steps:

1. sudo apt update
2. sudo apt full-upgrade
3. sudo apt dist-upgrade
4. sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
5. sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd
6. sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
7. sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
8. sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
9. sudo reboot now
10. Now connect to a wifi network using the new network manager you will find the the icon [image: NetworkManager Icon] on the task bar.
11. Select each connection and press the settings icon.[image: Select connection press settings in yellow]
12. Edit the settings menu to configure to your needs. The image is from selecting the mode pull-down list.[image: Configure WiFi connection Mode]

I've done this on a Pi Zero W with an external USB-Ethernet port to share the WiFi connection with a Ethernet only device. I've also tried this on a Pi 4 so it should work for you.

The information is based on the site:
https://dennymichael.net/2019/10/22/share-wifi-internet-with-ethernet-port-on-raspberry-pi-bridge/

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll try it!